# With an If statement, how can I skip a variable being checked if its property could be undefined?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I would like to be able to skip checking a variable if the property (.emailAddress) has the chance of being undefined but continue checking the others.

For example, I'm checking an entered email address if its an existing contact (email) on the page.

```
if(inputEmail.length > 0 && inputEmail.indexOf('@') > 0 */ check that the input is not blank & is probably an email address.

  && inputEmail !== existingContact1.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact2.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact3.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact3.emailAddress
)   {
// execute code
}
```

My problem occurs if .emailAddress is undefined, as you can't check undefined in an If statement. 
.emailAddress could be any combination of existingContact 1-4 that could be undefined or not.

- can’t check should read can’t compare undefined.

I've tried using typeof to find if it is undeclared with not the results I was expecting.

```
&& typeof existingContact1 == "undefined" || typeof existingContact1.emailAddress == "undefined" && existingContact1.emailAddress !== inputEmail
```

What are some diffrent approaches to be able to anticpte and skip over if .emailAddress has the chance of being undefined?

Comment: Have you tried "in"? Like "inputemail" in object.

Comment: "as you can't check undefined in an If statement." - this is untrue. You can by doing `if( typeof foo.bar  === 'undefined' )`.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I have not tried that.

Comment: You can just skip the `typeof` check and go straight to `if(x === undefined)`.

Comment: @Dai I worded that incorrectly. I should say I can’t compare the two if one is undefined. You receive an undefined error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

In programming `undefined` & `null` evaluate/return to false, so check like this

```
if(inputEmail && inputEmail.indexOf('@') > 0 */ check that the input is not blank & is probably an email address.

  && inputEmail !== existingContact1.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact2.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact3.emailAddress
  && inputEmail !== existingContact3.emailAddress
)   {
// execute code
}
```

Comment: This will perform a case-sensitive comparison - so if `inputEmail` is `foo@BAR.com` but if `existingContact1.emailAddress` is `FOO@bar.com` the check will fail, even though SMTP email addresses are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful thing about javascript is you *can* work with `undefined`. I highly recommend keeping everything as simple as possible at all times. Let's cover some cases:

1. You can literally assess with `===` operator if something is `undefined.` `===` returns true when the values on both sides are equal in value *and* type, which is how you'd check if a value is not defined in the most explicit way.
2. You can use a lazy falsy check, which is actually what I recommend. Using `!!x` (or just `x` in an If statement) will coerce it to boolean, and it will return true if `x` is a non-empty string and is not `undefined`.

I want to add as a footnote that I would recommend just keeping an array called `emailsOnPage` and then checking if `input.email` is in the array, rather than manually checking 4 conditions.

Robin mentioned the case insensivity of emails, and that's easy to do; just use the form `if(x.toLowerCase() == y.toLowerCase())`.

Answer (score 0):

try the approach like

```
var existingContact1 = { emailAddress: 'abc@zyz.com' }
var existingContact2 = { emailAddress: 'abc@zyz.com' }
var existingContact3 = { emailAddress: 'abc@zyz.com' }
var existingContact4 = { emailAddress: 'abc@zyz.com' }

if(inputEmail.length > 0 && inputEmail.indexOf('@') > 0 */ check that the input is not blank & is probably an email address.

  && [existingContact1, existingContact2, existingContact3, existingContact4]
        .map(({ emailAddress }) => emailAddress) // get existing emails 
        .filter(x => x) // remove falsy values if any
       .indexOf(inputEmail) > -1 // check if available
    )   {
    // execute code
    }
```